# Is it possible to load twilio.js library with webpack?

Tags: javascript, twilio, webpack

What i need is a way to bundle all my javascript dependencies into one javascript file with [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) (Just like with [socket.io-client](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client)), but i can't do that with twilio.js.

I can see that the latest of twilio.js is listed here.:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js as a script tag to:

> [//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js](https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js)

But this is just a loader script for building the real twilio.js library here:

> https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/refs/82278dd/twilio.min.js

And none of these supports Webpack.

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node also exsistes, but this is for node.js only - not just plain client side javascript.

So my question is, is there a way to require the twilio.js library with Webpack ?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for Twilio.js client version 1.3.16 ([script file](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/releases/1.3.16/twilio.js), [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js-13)).

The Twilio codebase is pretty bad. They don't publish their code to npm, and simply loading the twilio.js file from their CDN has side effects, including reading from `window` and looping through all script tags on the page. This means, even with the below answer, the client code can't be loaded in node, blocking server side rendering and testing, etc.

I published the [package to npm as a mirror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-client-mirror) of the code, but it's not straightforward to use. Webpack can't correctly handle whatever bogus require structure they have set up. First, install:

```
npm install --save twilio-client-mirror
```

Then to use, require as normal:

```
import * as loadTwilio from 'twilio-client-mirror';
```

However, you can't actually use the loadTwilio object. You have to reference the global Twilio object, injected by the script:

```
const Twilio = window.Twilio;
Twilio.Device.setup(token);
...
```

This is a first attempt I made to try to include this flaky code inside a modern codebase. Hopefully with the coming 1.4 beta they will address these issues.

Comment: Am I missing a step here? I'm attempting to use this in a React Native application, but I'm missing twilio/util and a bunch of the other twilio/* files.

Comment: Untested in React Native. There's only one built javascript file, not multiple.

Comment: If you take a look at the source for twilio-client-mirror/twilio.js though, you'll see that it has require statements for './twilio/util' and other similar files.

Comment: Yes, those require statements point to defined modules in that same script file. Maybe React Native environment (Node?) is running those requires and not using the require stubbed out in the file. I just copied the Twilio source script into the NPM package and didn't modify it. Again, it's not great code, which may be related here.

Comment: I'll have to do a bit more debugging at a later time. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I, too, just wrestled with this issue. Being new to Node, TypeScript and Webpack, I failed to understand that `Webpack` should be used for client-side scripts, while the `Twilio-node` library is a server-side library (as discussed loosely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897608/how-do-i-use-npm-installed-socket-io-with-typescript-and-webpack?answertab=active#tab-top)). In other words, you shouldn't use `require('twilio')` in any client-side scripts...only `Node` scripts.

I had success with the following:

1. Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.min.js"></script>` to my main `.html` page
2. Use `var twilio = require('twilio');` inside of a **Node** (server) script...**not** in client-side JavaScript (for example, add the Twilio calls inside of API methods, which can be created using a framework such as [Express](http://expressjs.com/))
3. If you happen to be using TypeScript for Node scripting, use a transpiler such as the native TypeScript transpiler [tsc](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) (easy to do from a command line). If using JavaScript, use [GulpJS](http://gulpjs.com/) (my fave) or [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) to help you consolidate and even run your Node server-side scripts
4. Use Webpack for anything else

Again, I'm new to this, so I'm open to input or corrections if I've stated anything incorrectly.