# How do I use NPM installed socket.io with TypeScript and webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, typescript, webpack

I am trying to use TypeScript with node, [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

I have set up `webpack.config.js`, `tsconfig.json` and `tsd.json` and downloaded the typings file for socket.io from the [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) using `tsd`. I have installed socket.io with `npm`.

When I run:

```
webpack
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/socket.io/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /private/tmp/ts-test/node_modules/socket.io/lib
 @ ./~/socket.io/lib/index.js 7:11-24
```

It appears webpack cannot resolve the inclusion of a module from within the node_modules directory.

My versions are:

- node v4.2.1
- tsd 0.6.5
- tsc 1.7.5
- webpack 1.12.11
- socket.io 1.4.4

I have published a small example to this repository: https://github.com/cubabit/typescript-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /private/tmp/ts-test/node_modules/socket.io/lib

That file *should not be loaded in the frontend*. You are loading the *backend / nodejs* javascript files of NodeJS.

Socket.io comes with both the backend and frontend.

## More

For a working example give http://alm.tools/ source code a go.

Comment: Is it not possible to use webpack on the backend? I am not compiling my typescript for the frontend

Comment: No. You don't need webpack for the backend! To compile for the backend use `grunt` or even just `tsc` e.g. `tsc -w -p ./src`

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes sense - thank you. I guess I need to work out how to compile the files into a dist dir because it seems messy all the js files being created all over the place alongside my ts files

Comment: @cubabit use `--outDir`